# QuickBooks Enterprise - What database does it use under the hood?

Tags: database, intuit-partner-platform, ipp-qbd-sync

The documentation makes note of a SQL database and database server.  Is it a standard database, or a custom DB made by intuit?  If it's a standard DB, what database and version?

Is it possible to connect to the database directly with a 3rd party application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Company file is a sybase file. Using API, you can interact with the company file ( that is what we call sync)

**Sync**  - [You App -> IDS Cloud -> Company File -> Upload data in persistent storage(cloud)]

Ref - 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0400_data_synchronization

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0300_sync_manager

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot connect directly to the underlying database.

Comment: Ha! The Intuit sales rep said it was running SQL Server, this was dubious to me as I don't see it mentioned anywhere on Intuit.com.

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise version comes with an ODBC read only connector.

Comment: The ODBC connector is actually provided by a third party and just provides a wrapper around the SDK, not access to the underlying DB: http://enterprisesuite.intuit.com/support/odbc.jsp

Comment: I think that information is outdated. See the following article http://www.sleeter.com/blog/the-new-odbc-access-in-enterprise-solutions-2011/